# How to get scoped public packages into Node-RED via palette?

Tags: npm, node-red

Last week I [published new public package to npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@smappee/node-red-contrib-smappee) for Node-RED with the keyword `node-red` but so far it has not shown up in the Node-RED Library; although it seems to adhere to the [packaging instructions](https://nodered.org/docs/creating-nodes/packaging).

One of the differences with other public packages is that these are published under an organization on npm. No other `@*` packages appear in the Node-RED Library but they do on npm.

How can I load a scoped public package via the palette manager in Node-RED?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before *2018-01-04* scoped packages were not indexed apparently. Now support has been added for them and the scoped packages I published appear online.

Plenty of scoped packages have been added to the flow library since the change now. They can now be installed via the palette manager in Node-RED.